# Regex, PHP - finding words that need correction

Tags: php, regex

I have a long string with words. Some of the words have special letters.

For example a string "have now a rea$l problem with$ dolar inp$t"
and i have a special letter "$".

I need to find and return all the words with special letters in a quickest way possible.

What I did is a function that parse this string by space and then using “for” going over all the words and searching for special character in each word. When it finds it—it saves it in an array. But I have been told that using regexes I can have it with much better performance and I don’t know how to implement it using them.

What is the best approach for it?

I am a new to regex but I understand it can help me with this task?

My code: (forbiden is a const)
The code works for now, only for one forbidden char.

```
function findSpecialChar($x){
$special = "";
$exploded = explode(" ", $x);
foreach ($exploded as $word){
   if (strpos($word,$forbidden) !== false)
     $special .= $word; 
}
return $special;
}
```

Comment: What i did is a function that parse this string by space and then using "for" going over all the words and searching for special character in each word. When it finds it - it saves it in an array. But i have been told that using regexes i can have it with much better performance and i dont know how to implement it using them

Comment: How long time does your current solution take?

Comment: Put all the information you have in the question.

Comment: Wiz - it doesnt take a lot now because i run it on a small input. It will later run on something huge and i had been told that regex performance is much better than using for and parsing. Is it correct?

Comment: Jake, i thought explaining the algo is enough. I will put the code in a minute

Comment: I posted a REAL code :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/preg_match) like this:

```
// Set your special word here.
$special_word = "café";

// Set your sentence here.
$string = "I like to eat food at a café and then read a magazine.";

// Run it through 'preg_match''.
preg_match("/(?:\W|^)(\Q$special_word\E)(?:\W|$)/i", $string, $matches);

// Dump the results to see it working.
echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
echo '</pre>';
```

The output would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  café
    [1] => café
)
```

Then if you wanted to replace that, you could do this using [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/preg_match):

```
// Set your special word here.
$special_word = "café";

// Set your special word here.
$special_word_replacement = " restaurant ";

// Set your sentence here.
$string = "I like to eat food at a café and then read a magazine.";

// Run it through 'preg_replace''.
$new_string = preg_replace("/(?:\W|^)(\Q$special_word\E)(?:\W|$)/i", $special_word_replacement, $string);

// Echo the results.
echo $new_string;
```

And the output for that would be:

> I like to eat food at a restaurant and then read a magazine.

I am sure the regex could be refined to avoid having to add spaces before and after `" restaurant "` like I do in this example, but this is the basic concept I believe you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. And what can i do if i have more than one special char that i am looking for? The original problem is that i am looking for words that got corrupted and have instead of letters, different chars like %, @, * ? and stuff like that

Comment: What do you mean? I posted the data i need to part in the example with the dolars... Thats what i have - corrupted strings and my job is to find the corrupted words.

Comment: And thanks for your answer, It helps to understand the concept